# Underscorejs : can template call itself

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Following is underscore template:
template name is navItems.html. i am using text plugin to load templates

```
<li>
     <a><%=data.title%></a>
      <p><%=data.attr%></p>
 </li>
```

which i am calling like this from backbone view

```
<%=_.template(navItemTpl,{'data':data})%>
```

is it possible to call template itself from inside template like
can i do?

```
 <%=_.template(navItemTpl,{'data':data})%>
```

inside navItem.html?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible.Added example code below:

HTML:

```
<div id="here"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="templ">
    <p id="container">
        <%= _.template($("#inner_templ").html(),{user:{"firstName":"some name"}}) %>
    </p>     
</script>    
<script type="text/template" id="inner_templ">
    <div><%=user.firstName%></div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var compiled = _.template($("#templ").html());
    $("#here").html(compiled());
});
```

Comment: I want to call <%=_.template(navItemTpl,{'data':data})%> in template itself.  ie can i call the same partial within itself.

Comment: When i try that i get "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". Why do you want to call the same template within a template.

Comment: I dont want to do iteration for specific levels because i dont know how many levels it is nested so for recursive use i am doing that.